# Handsonetable - can't hide columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, handsontable

I'm trying to hide few colums. Here is my code:

```
function setTable(options){

    var data = options.data;
    var container = options.container;
    var dataSchema = options.dataSchema;
    var colHeaders = options.colHeaders;
    var columns = options.columns;

    var table = new Handsontable(container, {
        data: data,
        disableVisualSelection:true,
        dataSchema: dataSchema,
        colHeaders:colHeaders,
        columns:columns,
        currentRowClassName: 'selected',
        columnSorting:true,
        columnStreching:true,
        autoColumnSize: true,
        stretchH: 'all',
        outsideClickDeselects: false 

    });
    Handsontable.hooks.add('afterSelectionEnd', function(e){
        var data = this.getDataAtRow(e);
        moveToAlert({
            n:data[1],
            v:data[4],
            lt:data[7],
            ln:data[8]
        });
    }, table);
    Handsontable.hooks.add('afterOnCellMouseOver', function(e,c){
        var data = this.getDataAtRow(c.row);
        if(data[0] == null) return false;
        moveToAlert({
            n:data[1],
            v:data[4],
            lt:data[7],
            ln:data[8]
        })
    }, table);

    return table;
}

actualData.push(
{
    reg:d.r, 
    name:d.n, 
    fd:d.fd, 
    td:d.td, 
    v:d.v, 
    rgps:d.rg, 
    loc:"PL, Wrocław, Autostradowa Obwodnica Wrocławia",
    lt:d.lt,
    ln:d.ln,
    c:'a_'+d.c
}
);   
}

if (TABLE_ACTUAL) TABLE_ACTUAL.destroy();
TABLE_ACTUAL = setTable({
  data:actualData,
  container:document.getElementById('actual-table'),
  dataSchema:{reg: null, name: null, fd: null, td: null, v: null, rgps: null, loc: null, lt:null, ln:null,c:null},
  colHeaders:["Pojazd", "Nazwa", "Od", "Do", "Wartość", "Droga", "Lokalizacja"],
  columns:[
    {
        data:"reg",
        editor:false,
    },
    {
        data:"name",
        editor:false,
    },
    {
        data:"fd",
        editor:false,
    },
    {
        data:"td",
        editor:false,
    },
    {
        data:"v",
        editor:false,
    },
    {
        data:"rgps",
        editor:false,
    },
    {
        data:"loc",
        editor:false,
    }
],
});
```

So i want to hide 3 last columns ( lt,ln,c) and also disable editor on all colums.  Why this way not working? I dont want to use customrender becouse i think its unnecessary.

**EDIT** 
SOLVED (thanks to @ZekeDroid)

I used getSourceDataAtRow() instead of getDataAtRow(). 
Also used fix for sorted table: http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/demo-sorting-data.html and more specifically this : `physicalIndex = instance.sortIndex[logicalIndex][0];` as a index for selected row.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? could you show a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely due to the `dataSchema` option. You are including the columns to show there, even if null. Try removing the `dataSchema` option entirely. But please provide a fiddle so we can be more sure about it.

Comment: If i remove them from `dataSchema` they are hidden but also i cant get this data from `getDataAtRow()`. I hope you understand what i mean :) In hook `afterOnCellMouseOver` i take data from row and i need `lt` and `ln` but dont want to display them. Soon gonna add fiddle.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could use the `metaData` method instead and it would show the hidden data, let me double check

Comment: try `getSourceDataAtRow()`

Comment: That helps alot. But what about sorted columns? When table is not sorted everything is working, after sort inexes of rows are not same as sourceData. How to fix it?

Comment: OK i got solution. http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/demo-sorting-data.html  just use this  `physicalIndex = instance.sortIndex[logicalIndex][0];`. Thanks for help :)

Comment: exactly, sorting uses logical indices so you have to use that line to get the physical index